# Passing an input value to a select option to another page using POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have an input text from form1.php that I want to pass to form2.php that has a select option, and i'm trying to get whatever the input text from form1.php to be the selected option in form2.php.

It looks straight forward when trying to pass a select value to an input, but i'm stuck when i turn things around.

**form1.php:**

```
<form class="form1" action="form2.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="inputval">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**form2.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
<select name="productselect" id="productselect">
<option>Car</option>
<option>Bus</option>
<option>Plane</option>
<option>Sail Boat</option>
</select>
}
else{}
?>
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In form2, look at the value of `$_POST['inputval']` is, and use that to mark the selected option. If you read up on the syntax of the html `option` tag, you will see how to decide which is pre-selected. As it's a hard-coded list, it will be a bit more code than if it were coming from a database or an array, so you could move the options to an array and loop through them. Then you only have one check to do, rather than one for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check in each select option if the value of `$_POST['inputVal']` is the same as the option, and if so add `selected="selected"` to mark it as selected option.

Also take into account that if no option is marked as selected, the first one will be selected automatically.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    ?>
        <select name="productselect" id="productselect" >
            <option <?php if($_POST['inputVal'] == 'Car') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>> Car</option >
            <option <?php if($_POST['inputVal'] == 'Bus') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>> Bus</option >
            <option <?php if($_POST['inputVal'] == 'Plane') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>> Plane</option >
            <option <?php if($_POST['inputVal'] == 'Sail Boat') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>> Sail Boat </option >
        </select >
    <?php
} else {
}
```